# Define quadrant based on positive/negative values in two columns

Tags: function, r, loops, if-statement

I have a data set with two columns of positive and negative numbers.  I would like to create a third column that reflects which quadrant they would appear in if plotted in Cartesian space.

For example, if Column A is positive, and Column B is positive, then Column C would record "I."  If column A is negative, and Column B is negative, then Column C would record "III," and so on.

I suspect I can do this with an `if else` function and then `loop` or `apply` it across rows in the data set, but my attempts to write the `if else` have so far failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the following would give you values between 1 and 4:

```
C <- (A<0) + (B<0)*2L + 1L
```

This transforms the whole column in one go. The magic lies in that FALSE/TRUE is treated as 0/1, and you can do math on it. By using 2L and 1L instead of 2 and 1, you keep the result as integers instead of forcing a coercion to doubles (which is slower and takes more memory).

Then assuming you want to map to these quadrants:

```
       +B
        |
     II | I
-A -----+---- +A
    III | IV
        |
       -B
```

You could use this (updated to use a data.frame):

```
# Sample data.frame with columns a & b
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,-1,-1,1), b=c(1,1,-1,-1))

quadrantNames <-  c('I', 'II', 'IV', 'III') # Your labels...
d <- within(d, c <- quadrantNames[(a<0) + (b<0)*2L + 1L])
head(d) # print data
   a  b   c
1  1  1   I
2 -1  1  II
3 -1 -1 III
4  1 -1  IV
```

...and if you want the quadrants mapped differently, just change the order of the labels in `quadrantNames`.

Comment: Am I going crazy or do you want those inequalities to go the other way...?

Comment: [Edit] Joran is correct, the inequalities should be going the other way.  Thanks to both of you for such quick responses!  That was much easier than what I had in mind.  Out of curiosity, what does the "L" represent?

Comment: @jslefche - The L is just telling R to store the number as an integer rather than a double. You'll find this trick often if you look at enough R functions as it can speed up your code.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I'm a bit slow, but this doesn't work for me.  If A is negative and B is negative, the code puts it in the fourth quadrant when it should be in the third.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Again, I updated the post with new labels and a 'nice' chart ;-).

Comment: Thanks Tommy.  In the interim, I went with the somewhat inelegant:

`data.frame$c[data.frame$a>=0) & (data.frame$b>=0)]="I"`
`data.frame$c[data.frame$a<=0) & (data.frame$b>=0)]="II"`


and so on.

Comment: OK, I updated to use a data.frame.
...and if the answer was what you need, you should mark is as an answer. You should also upvote answers (and questions) you like. Just click on the score in the upper left!

Comment: Glad we could get it..thanks for your persistence!  Marked as answered!